# get started with Paypal Pro API

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am working for a company that is using Paypal pro. There are so many Paypal account types, API's, and SDK's that I am starting to get confused with it all. At developer.paypal.com, there is documentation for many different things. What API and/or documentation do I use to start integrating paypal into my website? What is the difference between all these different ones?

Any advice or help would be great, as I am stuck.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would avoid the REST API and stick with the Classic API for now.  The REST API is very new and doesn't do (much) more than the Classic APIs do.  In fact, the Classic API is much more mature has a lot more functionality, which is one of the reasons I still prefer and recommend it.

With PayPal Pro you will use one of two APIs depending on which version you have.

- Website Payments Pro 3.0 - This uses the [DoDirectPayment API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoDirectPayment_API_Operation_NVP/)
- Payments Pro 2.0 - This uses the [PayFlow API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#submitting-credit-card-transactions).

Payments Pro 2.0 is actually the newer version.  If you're interested in more detail on that you can take a look at my article on the [History of PayPal Payments Pro](https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-payments-pro-dodirectpayment-vs-payflow/).

So those would be for direct credit card processing through your site / application from your own custom checkout page.  To add PayPal payments to that, you would use [Express Checkout APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/express-checkout/).  Specifically,

- [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)
- [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/)
- [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/)

If you are working with PHP this [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) will make all of these calls very simple for you.